# Visual Studio HTML Snippets. No 'td' or 'tr'?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

Are there any Visual Studio Snippets for tr or td?
I just want to type 'td', hit tab, and have it expand into

```
<td></td>
```

This seems fairly basic but I'm unable to find this anywhere. I downloaded the HTML Snippet Pack from Visual Studio Marketplace, and even that didn't have them.

Comment: are you using razor?

Comment: Humm is there any Emmet (does that and much more) extension for V.S?

Comment: I am using Razor. And I'm not able to find Emmet for V.S. 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it still blows my mind that I couldn't find any premade 'td' or 'tr' snippets included in any snippet packages.

But it turns out creating your own snippet is relatively easy. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

For the curious, here is my 'td' snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<CodeSnippets  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">  
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">  
        <Header>  
            <Title>HTML td</Title>
            <Author>Ethan Fischer</Author>
            <Shortcut>td</Shortcut>
        </Header>  
        <Snippet>  
            <Code Language="HTML">  
                <![CDATA[<td>$end$</td>]]>  
            </Code>  
        </Snippet>  
    </CodeSnippet>  
</CodeSnippets>
```

To get it working in VS2015, I saved this snippet as a .snippet file in

```
Visual Studio 2015/Code Snippets/Visual Web Developer/My HTML Snippets
```

Then, in Visual Studio, I opened the snippet manager (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+B), clicked 'Import...', found the .snippet file I just created, and added it to one of the suggested locations.

Voilà! Typing 'td' and pressing tab results in

```
<td></td>
```

with the cursor in between tags ($end$ tells the snippet where to place the cursor).